# Python 3.3 Loop with three inputs (lists)?

Tags: python

Im relatively new to python and i need to write a script that will add an amount to another amount using lists.. It will read the people, original amounts and bonus amounts, and then add the original and bonus together for example the output should be something like (with the name being amy, original amount being 1000 and bonus amount being 50)

"Amy now has $1050"
It should then loop and calculate the rest of the list of people along with the original and bonus amounts.

As shown below, this is as far as ive gotten, however its clearly a long way off what i need, as this can only pull in one list at a time. Im very new to python.. So guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
originalamount = [1000, original2, original3]
person = [amy, person2,person3]
bonus = [50, bonus2, bonus3]

def CalculateTotalAmount():
    for i in bonus:
        print ("Amy now has: %r" % i)
```

Answer (score 4):

Zip the lists and then unpack:

```
for a, p, b in zip(originalamount, person, bonus):
    print(a, p, b)
```

`zip()` creates a sequence of tuples with matching elements from each list. Then the for unpacking syntax is used to get the elements from each tuple into separate variables for easier processing.